# Show new Window with DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, viewmodel

I want to simply display my `UserControl` in a separate window, for example by calling

```
var windowHandler = new WindowHandler();
windowHandler.Show(new SchoolViewModel);
```

How do I archive this? I have tried the following:

Set the `DataTemplate` in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SchoolViewModel}">
            <view:SchoolUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In code-behind call it:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var windowHandler = new WindowHandler();
    windowHandler.ShowWindow(new SchoolViewModel(), 200, 200);
}
```

WindowHandler class:

```
public class WindowHandler
{
    public void ShowWindow(object dataContext, int height, int width)
    {
        Window window = new Window()
        {
            DataContext = dataContext,
            Width = width,
            Height = height
        };
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

It does show a window, but it's empty. Why is it empty? I also set the `DataContext` in the `UserControl`'s code-behind:

```
public SchoolUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: You never add your control to the window, you just put it in to a resource dictionary.

Comment: As a general rule, *never* explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl, regardless of what they tell you in blogs or online tutorial.

Comment: @BradleyUffner What do you mean by that?

Comment: You need a contentcontrol

Comment: @BradleyUffner But when i bind the ContentControl of the main window i can't really open the usercontrols in a new window right? Wouldn't contentcontrol only replace the current usercontrol?

Comment: The content control should pick up the data context of the window. And use the data template you declared automatically.

Comment: But honestly, this code has so many anti patterns in it, you Matt have other issues

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yeah well i am just trying to get a start. Most tutorials are (atleast the ones i found) only show how to set one view to a specific viewmodel, but not how to open up new windows with other viewmodels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window` is by default templated to show `Window.Content` and not `Window.DataContext`. So you should assign whatever you want to show as content:

```
public class WindowHandler
{
    public void ShowWindow(object dataContext, int height, int width)
    {
        Window window = new Window()
        {
            Content = dataContext,
            Width = width,
            Height = height
        };
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Also, as others noted, you should remove this line:

```
DataContext = this;
```

from your `SchoolUserControl`, because otherwise you won't have access to the templated view-model from within the control. And since `SchoolUserControl` is part of a `DataTemplate`, the templated view-model will be automatically available from `SchoolUserControl.DataContext`.